# create Json array and get some object under of this array uses alasql

Tags: javascript, node.js, alasql

how can I convert this Json

```
{"GÖNDERİCİ_ADI":"Mehmet","GÖNDERİCİ_SOYADI":"Yağmur","GÖNDERİCİ_TC_KİMLİK_NO":"1234567676","GÖNDERİCİ_PASAPORT_NO":"42324","GÖNDERİCİ_UNVAN":"Doktor","GÖNDERİCİ_CINSIYETI":"Erkek:E","GÖNDERİCİ_UYRUK":"TC","GÖNDERİCİ_ÜLKE":"Türkiye","GÖNDERİCİ_IL":"İstanbul","GÖNDERİCİ_ILCE":"Fatih","GÖNDERİCİ_ADRES":"Karagümrük","GÖNDERİCİ_ADRES_KODU":"34091","GÖNDERİCİ_POSTA_KODU":"34987","GÖNDERİCİ_IRTIBAT_TEL_1":"2124567896","GÖNDERİCİ_IRTIBAT_TEL_2":"Yok","GÖNDERİCİ_E_MAIL":"cakmak@fkf","GÖNDERİCİ_MESLEK":"dene"}
```

to like this

```
{"GONDERICI":[
{
"ADI":"MEHMET",
"SOYADI":"YAĞMUR",
"TC_KIMLIK_NO":"1234567676",
"PASAPORT NO":"42324",
"UNVAN":"Doktor", 
"CINSIYETI":"Erkek:E",
"UYRUK":"TC",
"ULKE":"TURKIYE",
"IL":"İstanbul",
"ILCE":"FATİH",
"ADRES":"Karagümrük", 
"ADRES_KODU":"34091",
"POSTA_KODU":"34987",
"IRTIBAT_TEL_1":"2124567896",
"IRTIBAT_TEL_2":"Yok",
"E_MAIL":"cakmak@fkf",
"MESLEK":"dene"
} ]
}
```

I want to add this Array **"GONDERICI"** and get object under of **GONDERICI** array

how can I do this?

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted so far by providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before adding your code.